# Excel VB Searching for text on a webpage and Copying information in the same Element

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am relatively new VBA.

I am trying to use this code to grab a bit of information from a website. When I do it by Element I have to search for the tag name which is `tr` and use a number next to it to define which one I want to use. The problem with that is it changes frequently with the position on the website. Currently the Keyword I want to search for and the information it contains is like so:

```
<tr>
  <td class="nt">Operations</td>
  <td>Windows</td>
</tr>
```

So if I can search by the class "Operations", and get the information "Windows", that would help. Also, I currently having an error

> Next without For

If possible, is there a way I can use this to do multiple searches before I close the page? So I look for multiple specific words and input that data into different cells before moving onto the next column where it would repeat until completed at the end of the x value. I currently only have it set to x=2 To 5 but I would like to increase that to 10 or higher in the future.

The current code looks like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  For x = 2 To 5
    If Target.Row = Cells(x, 35).Row And _
    Target.Column = Cells(x, 35).Column Then
    'If Target.Row = Range("ManufacturerPartNumber").Row And _
    'Target.Column = Range("ManufacturerPartNumber").Column Then
        Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
        'IE.Visible = True
        'For x = 2 To 5
        'IE.navigate "" & Range("Website_1").Value
        IE.navigate "" & Cells(x, 35).Value
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Dim sDD As String
        sDD = InStr(1, IE.document.body.innerHTML, "Processor Model")
        'sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("Processor Model")(1).innerText) 'Use this with tag like dd and number for which it appears like 0 or 1
        IE.Quit
        Dim aDD As Variant
        aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
        Cells(x, 44).Value = aDD(0)
        'Range("ProcessorNumberCd").Value = aDD(0)
        'Range("OSProvided").Value = aDD(0)
    Next x

    End If

  'MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Next x` is inside the `If` statement so it doesn't match up. You need to move it outside

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to grab the 'inner text'.  Take a look at the example below.

[image]

```
Sub Scraper()

   Dim item As Long
   Dim priceStr As String
   Dim priceTag As Object
   Dim priceTable As Object


   item = "10011" 'this will eventually be placed in a loop for multiple searches

   Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   objIE.Visible = True
   ' navigate and download the web page
   objIE.Navigate "www.google.com"
   Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 Or objIE.Busy
     DoEvents
   Loop

  'objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = item
  'objIE.Document.getElementByID("FDI").Click

  Set priceTable = objIE.Document.getElementByID("price_FGC")
  Set priceTag = priceTable.getElementsByTagName("u")(3)
  priceStr = priceTag.innerText

  Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = priceStr

  objIE.Quit


  End Sub
```

Also, check out this link for several other ways of how to do other, similar things.

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/index.htm